# Background image seems stretched in width, how can I fit it to the screen perfectly?

Tags: html, css

So for the life of me I don't know why the background image I designated seems to stretch in width. I looked up for many solutions and tried them but either the background will show only the upper right corner of the image or the upper left corner of the image. 
This is the sample PSD I have:

[PSD Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/humGx.png)

With my current settings the image is stretched in width for desktop browser.
Here how it looks for me:
[Stretched Background Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XklEk.jpg)

Below are part of my HTML markup and CSS settings, I designated the background image for html element. I tried background-size:cover but it didn't work.
**[You can ignore the foreign language in the HTML snippet]**

```css
/*--------Global--------*/

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  background: url('../img/background.png');
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  margin: 0;
}


/*--------Layout--------*/

.main-container {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}


/*----Flex----*/

.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.align-center {
  align-items: center;
}

.content-center {
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>RenTap</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/main.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main-container flex align-center content-center">
    <main>
      <img class="logo" src="img/logo.png">
      <h1>REN<span class="tap">TAP</span></h1>

      <div class="user-info">
        <input class="username" type="text" placeholder="שם משתמש">
        <br>
        <input class="pass" type="password" placeholder="סיסמא">
        <br>
        <button>התחבר</button>
      </div>

      <div class="help-and-terms">
        <p>
          שכחת סיסמא?&nbsp&nbsp <a>לחץ כאן</a>
          <br>
          <label class="checkbox-label">
                        <input type="checkbox"> קראתי והסכמתי לתנאי ההשכרה של רנטאפ&nbsp <a>לתנאים</a>
                        <span class="checkmark"></span>
                    </label>
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="footer">
        <button class="facebook">
                    <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
                    התחבר באמצעות פייסבוק
                </button>
        <br>
        <button class="register">הרשמה</button>
      </div>
    </main>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You'll probably have to use a different background image for different (larger) screens.

Comment: So the problem is in the image itself and not my settings ?

Comment: @Dylan I tried background-size: cover, but the background will show a part of the background image only

Comment: Yep, if background-size: cover/contain; doesn't work for you, then the image itself is the problem.

Comment: @MartinSchulz the dimensions of the image is 1080 x 1920, is that is the reason why the image is the problem ? I am just trying to understand

Comment: 1080x1920? Assuming you're certain about that, this isn't going to work. You've got a landscape screen with a portrait background. OOops!

Comment: @enhzflep Thanks for the explanation. so no matter what, when displayed on desktop screens it will be stretched, I understand now. Thanks again

Comment: @MajdKharman - Yeah mate, that's basically what I'm getting at. To get around this problem, you can use CSS media queries in combination with several instances of the image in different shapes. The browser will then automatically select the appropriate background for the screen-size of the viewing device. More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: @enhzflep I will look into it, many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
html {
background-size:cover;
background-position:center center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Probably image has to be larger 720p